# Using a PrintWriter to write ASCII codes to a file

Tags: java, ascii, printwriter

I want to know that when I use `PrintWriter` for writing to a file.  It will write with ASCII code in the file or binary format?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between ASCII and binary format do you expect? All are binaries in disk file.

Comment: printWriter is not byteOriented IO. I think it belongs to buffered line-oriented IO classes.

Answer (score 3):

A [`Writer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) writes characters, so the binary data that ends up in the file depends on the encoding.

For example, if you have a 16-bit encoding like UTF-16 then there will be an extra zero byte for each ASCII byte:

```
public class TestWriter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-16");
        final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

        writer.printf("abc");
        writer.close();

        for (final byte b : baos.toByteArray())
        {
            System.out.printf("0x%02x ", b);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

prints `0xfe 0xff 0x00 0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00 0x63`.

Answer (score 0):

It will output character data. But this can be beyond the ASCII set, which holds only 128 characters, of which the first 32 are special control characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write most ASCII letters as text or binary and you will get the same outcome with most characters encodings. Two of the ASCII characters have a special meaning in text files, are newline \n and carriage return \r.  This means that if you have text file and you want to write a String which contains these characters it can be hard or impossible for the reader to distinguish between end-of-line in the text file e.g. println() and end-of-line you put in a String e.g. print("1\n2\n3\n")